# Почему не выводится результат для отрицательных чисел?

Tags: c++

```
int a[10], i, n;
cout << "enter the number to convert: ";
cin >> n;

if (n > 0) 
    {
        cout << "binary of the given number: ";
        for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
        {
            a[i] = n % 2;
            n = n / 2;
            cout << a[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "binary of the given number: ";
        for (i = 0; n > 0; i++) 
        {
            a[i] = n % 2;
            n = n / 2;
            if (a[i] == 1) a[i] = 0;
            else a[i] = 1;
            cout << a[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я быть может ошибаюсь, но если мои глаза меня не подводят, то у вас у самого в условии написано n > 0, то есть n < 0 игнорируются

Comment: плюс в самом цикле написано: n > 0, хотя при входе отрицательных чисел это уже не удовлетворяет условию

Comment: Вы уточните пожалуйста какое решение ожидается при вводе отрицательных чисел? Работа с обратным кодом или значение должно быть то же самое, что и у положительного числа?

Comment: @david , при вводе отрицательного числа должен выводиться обратный код

Answer (score 3):

Рассмотрим машинное представление чисел:

- Прямой код исходное двоичное число. (модуль в случае отрицательного)
- Обратный код инвертированный прямой код (то есть единицы заменены
  нулями, а нули — единицами).
- Дополнительный код обратный код, увеличенный на единицу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас 2 основные ошибки:

1. Вы неверно выводите цифры двоичного кода (в обратном порядке)
2. Вы используете неправильную схему представления отрицательного числа.

Вот пример программы

```
#include <iostream>
#define BITS 8

using namespace std;
int main()
{


    int a[BITS], i, n,w,d;
    cout << "enter the number to convert: ";
    cin >> n;
    //Обнулим биты
    for (i = 0; i < BITS; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }


    if (n > 0)
    {

        for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
        {
            a[i] = n % 2;
            n = n / 2;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        n = abs(n);
        //двоичный код модуля
        for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
        {
            a[i] = n % 2;
            n = n / 2;
        }
        //инвертируем биты
        for (i = 0; i<BITS; i++)
        {
            a[i] = (a[i]+1)%2;
        }

        //Прибавляем 1
        w = 1;
        for (i = 0; i < BITS; i++)
        {
            d = a[i] + w;
            a[i] = d % 2;
            w = d / 2;
        }
    }
    cout << "binary of the given number: ";
    //мы не можем сразу получить битовое представление, 
        //так как при переводе цифры получем в обратном порядке
    for (i = BITS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << a[i];
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

отрывок из вашего кода:

```
if (n > 0) 
    //...
else   // значит n <= 0
    //...
    for (i = 0; n > 0; i++)
```

вход в цикл не будет, поскольку условие инструкции for не выполняется. Замените на `n != 0;`

**Обновление:**

Если вам нужно только выводить битовое представление, то для этого не нужно ничего хранить, и не нужны никакие условия, а просто нужно выводить все биты числа:

```
int n = 0;
cout << "enter the number to convert: ";
cin >> n;
cout << "\nbinary of the given number: ";  
const int bits = 8; //выводим первый байт
// вывод от старших битов
for (int i = bits - 1; i >= 0; --i) {       
    if (i == bits / 2 - 1)
        cout << ' ';   //пробел между полубайтами
    cout << (1 & (n >> i)); // получить i _тый бит
}
```

Comment: Исправил, но все равно выводится результат для положительного числа при вводе отрицательного

Comment: не выводится то что ожидали ? Верно, для получения бинарного представления отрицательных чисел, код не подходит